# R: How to plot multiple lines in one plot using a loop in ggplot

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2

I'm creating plots with ggplot in R and I used a loop in order to speed up my plotting time. However I have issues plotting multiple lines in the same graph. 
Data:

```
     df <- c("Results", "Capacity", "Power", "LDI","LDE", "LB", "PDC","D")
```

Some data

```
  Results Capacity Power  LDI      LDE  PDC   D     CperkWh
1 ImpactDC     1.00  PG20 LDI0.01  LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.010950532
2 ImpactDC     0.95  PG10 LDI0.02  LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.080374607
3 ImpactDC     0.90  PG50 LDI0.003 LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.010158171
4 ImpactDC     0.85  PG5  LDI0.05  LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.006994843
5 ImpactDC     0.80  PG3  LDI0.02  LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.009684512
6 ImpactDC     0.75  PG20 LDI0     LDE0 PDC0 D10 0.007891302
```

The loop I'm using is based on [here](http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/loops_with_ggplot2.html) and looks like this:

```
Power.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
  Powerlist <- unique(df$Power) 
  for (i in seq_along(Powerlist)){
    plot <- 
      ggplot(subset(df, df$Power==Powerlist[i]),
             aes(Capacity, y = CperkWh), group = df$Power, colour = PDC) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12))+
      facet_wrap( ~ PDC, ncol =1)+
      theme(legend.position = "none")+
      scale_y_continuous("Income  in €/kWh")+
      scale_x_continuous("Capacity of the line")+
      ggtitle(paste(Powerlist[i], ' Capacity of the line \n', 
                    "Income per kWh \n",
                    sep=''))
    #save plot as PNG 
    ggsave(plot = last_plot(), file= paste(StoreResults, '/Results/',
                                           Powerlist[i], "YesDCNoV2G.png", sep=''), scale=2)
    print(plot)
  }
}
#Run the function  
Power.graph(df)
```

What I would like to do is to plot multiple lines (so the graph CperkWh) for every value of LDI seperately. When I run the programme the plot I receive is what I want, however the geom_line command connects all the points and I would like it to only connect the point with the same value of LDI. This is what happen now: [image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, rather than just your column names?

Comment: Seems like you might need to move `group` inside of `aes`.  Try adding a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so folks can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the tips: I have added some data.

Comment: @aosmith I moved the group part inside the aes, but nothing change: the lines are still attached to each other.

Comment: If you want to only connect lines for the same `LDI` value, then you can use `group = LDI` inside of `aes`.  I think your `colour` should also be moved inside of `aes`,

Comment: It looks like maybe you want `ggplot(df, aes(Capacity, CperkWh, colour=LDI)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + facet_grid(Power ~ PDC)`.

Comment: @aosmith adding group =LDI did the trick!

Comment: @eipi10 yes I do want something like that, however my dataset and variable are rather large so I needed something to speed up the naming/saving part. I though this was a better way to do this.

Comment: How will you tell the groups apart?  This is often done with aesthetics like `linetype` or `color`.  Map your variable to one of those aesthetics and you will get a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say what are you trying to do without your data, but why do you need this loop at all? Something like this should work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Capacity, y = CperkWh, group=factor(Powerlist), color = PDC)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: I tried to use a loop since I have more variables (there are several values of P) than I'm actually showing in the example and I would like to automatise the whole proces. That's why I decided to try to create a loop. I'm new to R so I'm not sure if this is the best way, but for this is almost what I would like it to do.